# Unable to detect NVIDIA GPU on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia

I am unable to detect the GPU (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650) after loading Ubuntu 20.04 onto the Surface Book 3. I've reinstalled multiple times trying various solutions I've found, but I am at a loss and could really use some help detecting the GPU so I install CUDA + CUDNN for my work.

Running `lspci -k` does not show any nvidia devices and I am not able to see any "Additional Drivers" in **Software & Updates** as it is empty. Here's some info to show you what I've done so far:

UEFI Settings:

- Secure Boot = `disabled`
- DGPU = `enabled` (tried disabled as well, but no difference)

System attributes:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64
Host: Surface Book 3 124I:00037T:000
Kernel: 5.13.0-48-generic
Packages: 1631 (dpkg), 7 (snap)
Shell: bash 5.0.17
Resolution: 3000x2000
DE: GNOME
Terminal: gnome-terminal
CPU: Intel i7-1065G7 (8) @ 3.900GHz
GPU: Intel Iris Plus Graphics G7
```

Here's some terminal stuff I've run to find the GPU and understand the problem. Nothing changed after trying to install an nvidia driver:

```
# Because I disabled Wayland
~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE

x11
```

```
~$ uname -a

Linux mithras 5.13.0-48-generic #54~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 2 23:37:17 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G7 (rev 07)

`Subsystem: Microsoft Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G7`

`Kernel driver in use: i915`

`Kernel modules: i915`
```

```
~$ nvidia-smi

NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

```
~$ dmesg | grep NV

[ 0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007a03d000-0x000000007a03dfff] ACPI NVS

[ 0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007bb8a000-0x000000007bbb3fff] ACPI NVS

[ 0.269945] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x7a03d000-0x7a03dfff] (4096 bytes)

[ 0.269945] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x7bb8a000-0x7bbb3fff] (172032 bytes)

[ 0.277651] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
```

```
~$ dmesg | grep nvidia

[ 5.132779] audit: type=1400 audit(1641790599.087:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=585 comm="apparmor_parser"

[ 5.132782] audit: type=1400 audit(1641790599.087:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=585 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

I also tried running `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-nvidia` and `ubuntu-drivers devices`, but both came back empty.

I tried installing the drivers (510, 495, and 470) as well as dpkg versions from ppa, but nothing worked. I also made sure there were no nvidia blacklists in `lib/modprobe.d/` and `etc/modprobe.d/` as well as removing files `/lib/dev/rules.d/50-pm-nvidia.rules` and `/etc/dev/rules.d/80-pm-nvidia.rules`.

Please let me know if there's any additional information that will help.

Comment: Have you checked for any firmware updates from the vendor?  Have you run sudo apt-get update before trying to install the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: I made sure to run `sudo apt-get update` before installing drivers, but I didn't think to try the firmware updates. I found a way to install the firmware (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=101315) in ubuntu using this package (https://github.com/linux-surface/surface-uefi-firmware). I will try that shortly and let you know how it goes.